# Подпапки в папке ресурсов raw

Tags: android, android-resources

А есть ли возможность создать подпапку в `raw`? У меня очень много картинок, и хочу всех разбить по папкам.

Comment: В `raw` нельзя, можно в `assets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности нет. Структура директорий с ресурсами строго определена.
Поддиректории поддерживаются в папке `assets`, но в таком случае ресурсы не будут доступны через `R.*.*`, и придется вытаскивать их с помощью [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: А можете написать полный код, чтобы можно было открыть файлы, при нажатии на вариантов из список.

Comment: @akmaltilloev уточните задачу, пожалуйста. какие ресурсы нужно открыть, и в каком контексте?

Comment: Вот например у меня 3 текстового файла. И два `Activity`, в одной из них `ListView`, а в другой `WebView` в который загружаем текстовый файл. Сейчас у меня при клике на список чтение идёт с ресурового папка `raw`. Но я хочу чтобы чтение происходило из папки `asset`.

Comment: Чтение из `assets` очень похоже на чтение из `raw`. На выходе получает тот же `InputStream`. `AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("test.txt");`

Comment: Но тут открывается файл который задали его название.

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: А у меня там несколько файлов. Хочу чтобы как в raw файлы открылись по позициями

Comment: Вы имеете в виду доступ к файлам по типу `R.raw.file`?

Comment: Я совсем запутался. Можете сбросить структуру и содержимое директории `asset`, и указать какой именно файл вам нужно открыть?

Comment: Можете скинуть полный код для чтение? А дальше сам разберусь и вас не буду изучать!

Comment: Вот тут вроде бы более-менее нормально описан процесс: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php

Comment: Спасибо прочитаю.